# Spring data jpa: No property flush found for type void

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA to develop a Spring MVC app. I built a JPA repository.

```
public interface AccessReportRepository extends JpaRepository<AccessReport, Long> {    
}
```

I also use Spring Data Mongo along with JPA in my project.

When I run the project, I get this error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'lastDateController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.innolabmm.software.mongotest.springrest.ReadingService com.innolabmm.software.mongotest.springrest.LastDateController.readingService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readingService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.innolabmm.software.mongotest.springrest.AccessReportRepository com.innolabmm.software.mongotest.springrest.ReadingService.reportRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessReportRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property flush found for type void
```

Does anyone have an idea what is going on? I am ready to provide more information if this will help solve the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the bean you want initialize has some dependencies which initialized with injection, you need to either disable the DI in the desire bean, or check the dependencies, maybe they point to a resource that is not exist

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Spring Boot?

I had the same exception thrown when trying to use JPA and Mongo together, in a Spring Boot application. I found that the Repositories were always being interpreted by both JPA and Mongo, leading to problems as my repositories specifically extend `JpaRepository`.

I only wanted JPA repositories generated, so added the following to the Application entry point.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MongoDB with JPA (my JPA db is mysql) do this:

- create separete packages for domain objects and for repositories (DAOs): i.e. demo.mysql.domain, demo.mysql.dao, demo.mongo.domain, demo.mongo.dao
- in your configuration class use these annotations:

```
    @EntityScan(basePackages={"demo.mysql.domain"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"demo.mysql.dao"})
    @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages={"demo.mongo.dao"})
```

- annotate your JPA entities with @Entity and put them all in demo.mysql.domain package
- annotate your MongoDB entities with @Document and put them all in demo.mongo.domain package
- keep all of MongoDB reporitories in demo.mongo.dao package
- keep all JPA repositories in demo.mysql.dao package
- all mongo repositories should extend MongoRepository (i.e. public interface TransactionRepository extends MongoRepository)
- all JPA repositories should extend JpaRepository (i.e. public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository)

This is by far the easiest and the cleanest way that I have found (after digging through docs, btw.) to have MongoDB and Mysql working in one Spring Boot app.

That is what I have tried and what works. You could probably use MongoTemplate or extend CrudRepository instead of JpaRepository, or whatever else, try it, it might work.